# Changing Float Values with "Combo Box Selected Change"

Tags: c#, if-statement, combobox

I am trying to change Float values via a combo box with an if statement.

Id doesn't have to be an if statement but I figured it would of been the most logical way to approach this.

However when I try to change a float with an if statement from selected change on a combo box I get Namespace errors and definition errors...

I want it to reflect a formula later on in the program, **outside of the scope**, so the floats change based on what they have selected in the dropdown.

**My "IF" Statement**

```
public void cmbSubClass_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cmbSubClass.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {

               public float a = 0.86F; 
               public float b = 0.61F;
               public float c = 1.86F;  
            }
            if (cmbSubClass.SelectedIndex == 2)
            {
               public float a = 0.64F;
               public float b = 0.75F;
               public float c = 1.42F; 
            }
        }
```

**An example of the Formula:**

```
float zFormula = (a * val1) + (b * val2) + (c * val3)
textbox1.Text = Convert.ToString(zFormula);
```

I've tried to replicate the same thing with a class, but I can't seem to figure out how to do so.

Comment: `I get massive errors...` and then you don't tell us the errors?  Don't declare your variables inside the If block — they get restricted to just that block of code.

Comment: meaning it breaks the code, there is no "1" error for it. It just says nothing exists in the current context or nothing contains a definition.

Even if it is public it gets locked to the block? How would I change the values on a combo box selection then?

Comment: Declaring and setting the variable are two different things.  Move `public float a;` etc  above the SelectedIndexChanged line.

Comment: `Declaring and setting the variable are two different things.` Perfect, that fixed it. :) thanks.

Comment: Michal Zych answer is recommended over hard-coded indexes. Your code won't work if you decide to set `Sorted` property to `true` and it is very fragile if you decide to change the list of available values as you can easily get out of sync if you forget to update all code.

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this (using bindings):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Data> data = new List<Data>();
        data.Add(new Data("Set1", 1, 2, 3));
        data.Add(new Data("Set2", 3, 2, 3));
        comboBox1.DataSource = data;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var set = comboBox1.SelectedValue as Data;
        var val1 = 1;
        float zFormula = (set.A * val1) + (set.B * val1) + (set.C * val1);
        textbox1.Text = Convert.ToString(zFormula);
    }
}

public class Data
{
    public Data(string name, float a, float b, float c)
    {
        Name = name;
        A = a; B = b; C = c;
    }

    public string Name { get; protected set; }
    public float A { get; protected set; }
    public float B { get; protected set; }
    public float C { get; protected set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Declaring and setting the variable are two different things.

It made perfect sense after @LarsTech said that...

```
        public float a;
        public float b;
        public float c;
        public float d;
        public float f;

        public void cmbSubClass_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cmbSubClass.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                txtOutput.Text = ("class1 selected");
                a = 1.12F;
                b = 2.32F;
                c = 3.32F;
                d = 4.31F;
                f = 5.23F;

            }
            if (cmbSubClass.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                txtOutput.Text = ("class2 selected");
                a = 0.01F;
                b = 0.21F;
                c = 0.23F;
                d = 0.75F;
                f = 1.66F;
            }
            if (cmbSubClass.SelectedIndex == 2)
            {
                txtOutput.Text = ("class3 selected");
                a = 1.02F;
                b = 1.22F;
                c = 1.42F;
                d = 1.62F;
                f = 1.32F;

            }
        }
```

Problem solved.